# Submitting apps for iOS 13 (pre-release) process

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, ios13

I'm trying to find information about the schedule of submitting apps for review for iOS 13.

I do aware it's in beta phase (both Xcode, iOS, and MacOS).

From past iOS versions, I remember that they usually give you one/two weeks pre-official iOS release to submit the apps using GM version of Xcode (Xcode 11 in our case) but I wanted to check if there is already official doc supporting it.

Comment: Contact apple? This is not a question for so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the schedule of the Apple iOS 13 release :

**iOS 13 release date schedule**

> 1. June 3: iOS 13 beta 1 and first look at WWDC 2019
> 2. July: iOS 13 public beta release date for adventurous testers
> 3. Early September 2019: iOS 13 Golden Master (final dev beta)
> 4. Mid-September 2019: iOS 13 likely to launch with new 2019 iPhones

So if you see above there will be Golden Master release will be in early September. That will be almost like a final release for the developers point of view. So you can use that release for testing iOS 13 compatibility & features working or not.

So by this way you can be able to launch & schedule your release before the final release of iOS 13.

Hope this will help.

Comment: In other words, pretty much the exact same schedule as the last 10 years.

Comment: Not sure if this answers his question. I think he’s asking about submitting his ios13 app for review before ios13 is released. When can he start doing this?